# Bash autocomplete like zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, autocomplete

I'm using bash, but I'd like to have zsh style autocomplete (you hit tab and it tabs through the possibilities), rather than what bash seems to do, which is display a list of possibilities but not choose anything until I type some more to disambiguate. How can I get zsh type behavior in bash?

Searching for a solution has turned up lots of answers to other questions, so I'm hoping I can get a simple answer here (i.e. what to paste into my `.bashrc`).

(And to answer the obvious question, I need to use bash here because I just joined a team and they do some stuff to set up bash to make the environment easier to work in.  I can probably eventually make sure I have it working the same way in zsh, but for now it's easier if I use bash and just get it behaving more like zsh during interactive use.)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I use

```
bind 'TAB:menu-complete'
```

to achieve it

Comment: When I add this to my .bashrc, tab cycles through the possible options rather than listing them in the terminal. Is is possible to get both behaviors?

Comment: For `Shitf-Tab` to complete backwards, use `bind '"\e[Z":menu-complete-backward'`.

Comment: Add `bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous on'` to list available options in addition to cycling through with tab.

Answer (score 47):

To get first completion and a listing you can add the following to bashrc

```
bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous on'
bind 'TAB:menu-complete'
```

> show-all-if-ambiguous:
>      This alters the default behavior of the completion functions. If set to ‘on’, words which have more than one possible completion cause the matches to be listed immediately instead of ringing the bell. The default value is ‘off’.

see [Bash Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html) for more information.

Edit:

This doesn't make bash work *exactly* as zsh tho.
Zsh will complete up until the next ambiguous match. Bash will just cycle through all matches.

e.g.

`$ ls ~/.ba<tab>
.bashrc .bash_history .bash_profile`

- zsh: will complete up until ~/.bash and present a list of matches which handily enables you to append _ and hit `<tab>` again.
- bash: will just cycle through all ~/.ba* matches.

Comment: I liked using the arrow keys, and the visual indication of zsh's autocompletion. Is there a way to get those behaviors with bash? I switching back for better server compatibility

Comment: Why do you use the `bind` command before `set`? Isn't it enough to just set the setting to on? Are there any advantages?

Comment: I actually like the bash behavior better. Thanks for explaining this and giving the excellent answer!

Comment: @winklerrr we're setting a built-in variable of the readline library, for which you the `bind` command. You can list all the readline variables with `bind -v`.
What you're referring to is `set` which sets a bash variable.

Answer (score 21):

In Bash: Zsh like autocomplete can be achieved with [Ble.sh](https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh).

```
# Quick TRIAL without installation
# requires the commands git, make (GNU make), and gawk

git clone --recursive https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh.git
make -C ble.sh
source ble.sh/out/ble.sh
```

Here is a quick demo of Bash with blesh.
For more details see: [README](https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh/blob/master/README.md) of Ble.sh

[image]

Comment: May I know the reason why it's unnecessarily downvoted without any explanation? Please help to improve this answer by suggesting an edit instead of downvoting without any insightful and actionable details.

Comment: That's exactly what i was searching for! Thanks.

Comment: This is the best answer.
Dependencies for `ble.sh` are `gmake` & `gawk`. Prefer `gmake -C ble.sh`, if possible. To install under `~/.local/share/blesh` use `gmake install` (or `make install`) and then add `source /home/ipellegrini/.local/share/blesh/ble.sh` to your `.bashrc` (or `.bash_profile` on MacOS).

Comment: Love this answer. Works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on [ingkebil](https://superuser.com/users/386086/ingkebil)'s answer, for those that put `bind` and `set` into `inputrc`:

```
$ tail -n 4 /etc/inputrc
# zsh like completion:
# https://superuser.com/questions/288714/bash-autocomplete-like-zsh
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
TAB:menu-complete
```

I like keeping my `.bashrc` clean.

Comment: ... and instead pollute the system-wide `inputrc`? Fine if it's your personal system; dubious as general advice.